# Jenkins won't start due to port - won't accept command line port change or config file

Tags: jar, jenkins, port, command-line-arguments

I am calling

```
 java -jar /jenkins/jenkins.war -httpPort=8088
```

And have also set http port in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
to 8088

And yet I keep getting

```
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.HttpListener
at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:229)
at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:181)
at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:384)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at      sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at Main._main(Main.java:288)
at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to listen on port 8080
at winstone.HttpListener.getServerSocket(HttpListener.java:122)
at winstone.HttpListener.start(HttpListener.java:75)
at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:220)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
at winstone.HttpListener.getServerSocket(HttpListener.java:117)
... 10 more
```

I'm tearing my hair out here not understanding why it keeps trying 8080

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `--httpPort`, see also [Starting and Accessing Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins).

Comment: That's what happens when you stare at it for too long - thanks for the clear view - all good now